# what is interface () in objective C

Tags: objective-c

I read couple of blogs about interface and classes in objective C but I couldn't find what does `interface abc()` means

In Jitsi Code they have done something like this

https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/ios/sdk/src/JitsiMeetView%2BPrivate.h#L20

```
#import "JitsiMeetView.h"

@interface JitsiMeetView ()

+ (instancetype _Nullable)viewForExternalAPIScope:(NSString *_Nonnull)externalAPIScope;
+ (BOOL)setPropsInViews:(NSDictionary *_Nonnull)newProps;

@end
```

Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: This is an [extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3). If you search StackOverflow for [objective-c extension](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjective-c%5D+extension), you'll get many relevant answers.

Comment: See [Class Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3) in [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH1-SW1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, this is a class extension. The main key points of the `@interface` are:

- It is used to extend the existing methods of a class;
- It extends only the internal implementation (it can only be added to a class for which you have the source code at compile time);
- It is used to hide private information (as it is declared in the .m file, this means what's in the `@interface` cannot be accessed from outside (other classes).

As stated in the comments, for the full documentation please check [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html).

Comment: Class extensions can be used in other header files and to provide API and/or SPI declarations.  They just need to be visible to the compiler when the class itself is compiled to ensure that everything promised by the extension is really implemented correctly.